# Error trying to install Ansible in Jenkins image

Tags: jenkins, docker, ansible, dockerfile

I'm trying to install Ansible in my Jenkins image ([this way](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu)). This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins

USER root

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ansible

USER jenkins
```

But when I build the image, I get this error:

> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. Thet have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have realized that
`http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu/dists/jessie` doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: The guide is using ubuntu as OS base, try to use OS is ubuntu, so edit docker to : FROM ubuntu:14.04

Comment: Do `apt-get update` first

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Then I lose jenkins (I have to install it manually)

Comment: @user2915097 Do you mean before install software-properties-common?

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing to do in a Dockerfile

Comment: @user2915097 same error :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your above link, ansible ppa seems to have support only for ubuntu, so you end up adding a broken ppa. Your docker image `jenkins` inherits from `java:8-jdk` which further inherits from `buildpack-deps:jessie-scm` which inherits `buildpack-deps:jessie-curl` and that one from `debian:jessie`

From [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html)

> If you are wishing to run the latest released version of Ansible and
>   you are running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (TM), CentOS, Fedora, Debian,
>   or Ubuntu, we recommend using the OS package manager.

This means, if you have your Dockerfile like this

```
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil docker-ansible-jenkins]$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ansible
USER jenkins
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil docker-ansible-jenkins]$
```

Thats enough and I managed to test this and this works !

```
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil docker-ansible-jenkins]$ docker build -t jenkins --rm .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
...
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil docker-ansible-jenkins]$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 jenkins
e722efecdf7beb462bafaff653b19261268abbd2d56f88334ba6c42d068b2877
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil docker-ansible-jenkins]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
e722efecdf7b        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   focused_cray
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil docker-ansible-jenkins]$
```

Let us hear about how this went for you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3-pip -y && \
    pip3 install ansible --upgrade &&\
    apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get update

USER jenkins
```